# Comparing two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-comparison

Hi I want to compare two columns in a pandas dataframe to see if a value is in any row of a column.

Table: 1

```
| Animals_1 |  Count |
|-----------|--------|
|    Dog    |    1   |
|    Cat    |    2   |
|  Squirrel |    3   |
```

Table:2

```
| Animals_2 |  Count |
|-----------|--------|
|  Giraffe  |    2   |
|    Dog    |    1   |
|    Cat    |    1   |
```

So I want to check to see if Dog from table 1 is in any rows in column 1 of table 2.
I am new to python and using pandas to read table dataframe.

Comment: Search for `isin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Animals_1":["Dog","Cat","Squirrel"],"Count":[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Animals_2":["Giraffe","Dog","Cat"],"Count":[2,1,1]})
df1['compare'] = df1['Animals_1'].isin(df2['Animals_2'])
```

Output `df1`:

|  | Animals_1 | Count | compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dog | 1 | True |
| 1 | Cat | 2 | True |
| 2 | Squirrel | 3 | False |

Comment: I was going to use .iloc in a for loop, but this way is much better. Thank you.